# Joint distribution weird result

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

> We have 3x3 board   Each board cell has $0.5$ chance to be white
>   (there is no dependency between different cell colors)
>
> Let X = number of white rows (a row with only white cells on it)
>    Let
>   N = total number of white cells in the whole board
>
> Find $P\{X=0,N=3\}$
>   Find $P\{X=0 |N=5\}$

What I tried to do is to calculate the $P\{X=0,N=3\}$ , I said that:
$P\{X=0,N=3\}=P(N=3)*P(X=0|N=3)$ is it true?
Because now I got that it equals to $\frac{21}{128}*\frac{1}{168}=\frac{1}{1024}$
Which just seems way too low and also I'm not sure if I would change my answer if the question was to find $P\{X=0|N=3\}$ instead of $P\{X=0,N=3\}$ which seems odd to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that

$$P(X=0,N=3)=P(X=0\,|\,N=3) P(N=3)$$

We will find $P(X=0 \,|\,N=3)$ then $P(N=3)$ separately, then multiply them together.

---

**Part 1**: $P(X=0\,|\,N=3)$

With three white squares, there can be at most one white row. This means that if $N=3$, then $X=0$ or $X=1$ are the only possibilities. Therefore

$$P(X=0\,|\,N=3)=1-P(X=1 \,|\,N=3)$$

The total number of arrangements of the $9$ squares in the grid is $$\binom{9}{3}=\frac{9\cdot 8 \cdot 7}{3 \cdot 2} = 84$$

There are $3$ arrangements such that there is a white row.  That means

$$P(X=0\,|\,N=3)=1-\frac{3}{84} = 1-\frac{1}{28} = \frac{27}{28}$$

---

**Part 2**: $P(N=3)$

There are $\binom{9}{3}$ arrangements in which there are three white squares. Each of these arrangements has a $(1/2)^3(1/2)^6$ probability of occuring. Therefore

$$P(N=3)=\binom{9}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^9=\frac{21\cdot 2^2}{2^9}=\frac{21}{128}$$

---

Our final answer is therefore

$$P(X=0,N=3)=\left(\frac{27}{28}\right)\left(\frac{21}{128}\right)=\boxed{\frac{81}{512}}$$

Comment: Thanks, how would you change your answer if the question was $P(X=0|N=3)$ because right now I'm confused about when do you use conditionals and when not, also aren't you supposed to multiple your answer by $P(N=3)$? because right now the information about each cell chance to be white is ignored

Comment: @TheOne I was treating $P(X=0,N=3)$ to mean $X=0$ given $N=3$. My bad ... so for your notation does it mean $X=0$ and $N=3$? I will change my answer to fix it then.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, in our university they told as that $P(X=0,N=3)$ is known for $X=0$ And $N=3$ (the good thing is that now I understand how your answer would have looked if we went for the $P(X=0|N=3)$ which I wanted to understand as well :)

Comment: @TheOne I think I fixed it now :)